# Removing slide numbers from Beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, footer

I'm using the Frankfurt beamer theme, with infolines as my outer theme and would like to suppress all page/frame numbers

I have tried all the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320776/remove-the-slide-count-from-beamer-footer) and in the question linked there, but to no avail. My TeX distribution is the 2021 MikTeX, if that matters. My header looks like this. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[t,11pt]{beamer}

\linespread{1}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vspace*{-3pt}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{-3pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{equation* begin}{\vspace*{-3pt}}{}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test Frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done by emptying the `page number in head/foot` beamer template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this, but I still get page numbers when I compile it